# Oracle 10g - slow metadata queries

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We recently upgraded to 10g and I've noticed that metadata queries seem to take an extraordinarily long time (at a guess 2-5 times slower than on 9i).  Has anyone else noticed this?  Any suggestions on ways to rectify this problem (settings/patches/incantations)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to Oracle Metalink (MyOracleSupport, or whatever they're calling it today), look up bug #2475998, DRAMATIC DROP IN PERFORMANCE USING SYNONYMS VIA SETINCLUDESYNONYMS METHOD.  The submitter reported a 60x degradation of performance of DatabaseMetadata.getColumns() when synonyms exist.  Oracle recommends getting metadata in some other way e.g. execute a dummy query and get ResultSetMetaData.

Also see Jack Shirazi's [Java Performance Tuning](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003773), which has a section on [performance of obtaining database](http://books.google.com/books?id=7_dM2fWXTYkC&lpg=PA492&dq=oracle%20jdbc%20driver%20gettables%20analyze&pg=PA492) metadata.  (link to Google Books excerpt)

Bottom line is, don't use DatabaseMetadata.getColumns().